# How to send parking information to server in veins?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am using veins-4.7.1 and sumo-0.30.0. In my simulation i applied an algorithm to find the shortest path from vehicle current road to a parking area. Before applying the algorithm, vehicles need to make sure which park has a free space.

I defined parking area in  parking.add.xml file as follow:

**parkingArea id="ParkAreaA" lane="281572675#3_0" startPos="210" endPos="270" roadsideCapacity="10" width="15" length="30" angle="45" onRoad="false">**

How to send parking space information to the cloud server in veins?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The relevant TraCI interface function which Veins uses was not present in SUMO 0.30.0.

Comment: Thank you sir for your response. The cloud server i have mentioned in my post is a module in my simulation. I am new to omnet++, and i need  to send parking space information to the cloud server in order to make sure which park has a free space. Thanks.